# GUI: Advise if JTabbedpane should be used

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtabbedpane

GUI newbie.  I'm making a GUI that has multiple tabs of links.  The tabs in the GUI are like the product, services, etc tab on http://www.bestbuy.com/.  What would I use to create these tabs?  I have googled and the best answer I found is to use Jtabbedpane.  Please advise if this is correct.  Also, if it's Jtabbedpane, how do I change the size of the panel(?) (to be smaller) that appears after I click on the tab name?  Thank you!

Comment: show your code so far, what do your panels look like?

Comment: Do you want simple tabs, or the mini-panels with sub-tabs to appear after you mouse-over the tabs?

Comment: @Sionnach733 - I don't have any code yet because I don't know where to start...I want to plan out what I need to do before I write the codes.

Comment: @AndrewG - I want exactly what the Product tab does on www.bestbuy.com.  Is this what you mean by "mini-panels with sub-tabs to appear after you mouse-over the tabs"?

Comment: Hmm... I haven't tried this, but you might want to try creating fixed size and fixed location panels for each of your tabs, then call `setVisible(true/false)` according to whatever listener you use for your tabs. You'll probably want to build some barebones code and fiddle with it a little bit. Maybe post that code here once you're ready so we have a starting point. And *high five*. I know lots of coders who jump into projects without a plan more times than not, myself included. ;)

Comment: It depends.  Do you want ALL the products to be loaded at once or not?  With something like `JTabbedPane`, it's possible (although there are some complex ways to get around it) for all the products to be loaded at once.  Maybe instead, you could use something like a `JList` to display the top level categories (assuming they are only a single level) and when selected, a `CardLayout` to change the view or simply update the view's model with the appropriate values it needs to display...

Comment: @AndrewG  *"I haven't tried this, but you might want to try.."*  (teeth grinding)  We already waste enough time trying to correct the codes of people following this (bad) advice, we don't need more.  If your future comments have to be prefixed with *"I haven't tried this.."*  then please give considerable thought to the concept of 'remaining silent'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I said that because I wanted to let people know that I haven't proven it to be correct. But it is the first thing I would try if I wanted to do something similar. I thought I might mention it as a possible idea to try, but I have no time to experiment with it myself. I didn't know that attempting to help any way I can was an issue. I was simply bouncing idea around.

Comment: @AndrewG  *"I didn't know that attempting to help any way I can was an issue."*  Help at the extreme low end of the scale is 'noise'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, my help may not be the "pristine, thousand-line-code-example, super-simple" answer that gained you 19K reputation, but I figured with a "GUI newbie" who had no code so far, I might be able to provide an idea to point them in the right direction. I would on no scale call an attempt to do so: _"noise"_.

Comment: @AndrewG  *"I might be able to provide an idea to point them in the right direction"*  But that is just it.  Your idea was leading the OP in *exactly the wrong direction.*  ***Try it if you don't believe me.***

Comment: @AndrewThompson Calm down !! I thought it was hard to anger an Aussie ;-) I guess what OP is talking about is the hover-over property that is common in websites.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JTabbedPane` . That is all I can say.  This will let you create a tabbed pane as shown below:

[image]

**SSCCE:**

```
/*
 * Licence and stuff from Oracle.
 */
package components;

/*
 * TabbedPaneDemo.java requires one additional file:
 *   images/middle.gif.
 */

import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TabbedPaneDemo extends JPanel {
    public TabbedPaneDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/middle.gif");

        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Panel #1");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", icon, panel1,
                "Does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Panel #2");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", icon, panel2,
                "Does twice as much nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

        JComponent panel3 = makeTextPanel("Panel #3");
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", icon, panel3,
                "Still does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(2, KeyEvent.VK_3);

        JComponent panel4 = makeTextPanel(
                "Panel #4 (has a preferred size of 410 x 50).");
        panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 50));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 4", icon, panel4,
                "Does nothing at all");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(3, KeyEvent.VK_4);

        //Add the tabbed pane to this panel.
        add(tabbedPane);

        //The following line enables to use scrolling tabs.
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = TabbedPaneDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from
     * the event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add content to the window.
        frame.add(new TabbedPaneDemo(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Turn off metal's use of bold fonts
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Detailed explanation on the example above [can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html)

---

> how do I change the size of the panel(?) (to be smaller) that appears
>   after I click on the tab name?

By setting the preferred size of the `JPanel` that you put into the tab. However, it is discouraged to change the size manually. Let the layout manager manage that for you.